# How do I compare 2 arraylist in a for loop or foreach loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

I have 2 arraylist which I added its values dynamically, how do I compare them and check if they are equal in the loop? Something like this:

```
ArrayList answers = new ArrayList();

ArrayList choosen = new ArrayList();

// in some method
{
 answers.Add(qhm.Answer);
 choosen.Add(tbox.Text);
}
```

then in foreach loop

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Check Button
{
 int c = 0;
 foreach( //Compare two arraylist here)
  {

   if (answers == choosen) {
    c++;
   }
  }
  MessageBox.Show("You have answered : " + c + "questions correctly!");*/
 }
```

I want it like

> answer[1] = choosen[1]
>   answer[2] = choosen[2]

For example the first array stored in answers is equal to the first array stored in choosen.

Comment: `ArrayList` is seldom a good choice anymore. Consider using  `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int cnt = 0;
        foreach (var x in answers)
        {
            foreach (var y in choosen)
            {
                if (x == y)
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
```

In this you can use "Intersect" of linq also.

In your case the below will be the solution

```
for (int i = 0; i < answers.Count; i++)
{
    if (answers[i] == choosen[i])
    {
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is *not* how "arrays are equal" is usually defined - it is non-optimized implementation of Intersect (operation on sets) and hence ignores order. It is unlikely this assignment allows answers to be in different order than questions. Likely most basic usage of `for` is assumed.

Comment: i want it to be like  the first array stored in answers is equal to the first array stored in choosen .

Comment: It seems, that the solution is not always correct one: imaging answers = ["A", "A", "A"], choosen = ["A", "B", "C"].
The code returns 3 while 1 is correct, since only 1st asnwer ("A" = "A") is right.

Comment: Yes I agree..Now I have changed it.

Answer (score 1):

If all the answers's and choosen's items are Strings you can use Linq:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  int numberOfRightAnswers = answers.OfType<String>().Zip(choosen.OfType<String>(), (x, y) => x == y).Where(x => x).Count();
  int numberOfWrongAnswers = answers.Count - numberOfRightAnswers;
```

in order to simplify the code (ugly looking `answers.OfType<String>()` and `choosen.OfType<String>()`) you may use `List<String>` instead of ArrayList

Alternative loop implementation (assuming that answers and choosen are of the same size)

```
  int numberOfRightAnswers = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < answers.Count; ++i)
    if (answers[i] == choosen[i])
      numberOfRightAnswers += 1;      

  int numberOfWrongAnswers = answers.Count - numberOfRightAnswers;
```